# I have a valid US visa which is valid till 2030. I am planning to include my middle name i my renewed passport

Tags: visas, usa

I have a valid US visa till 2030. I intend to include my middle name in the passport when I renew it as my Aadhar card has the middle name and this is required to be entered in the form required for renewing my passport. The name given the visa is as given in the existing passport without my middle name. I will have two posts in daily newspaper on the change of name on the basis of a  notarized document for change of name. Will I face difficulties on entering the US?

Answer (score 4):

Directly from the Department of State

If your name has legally changed through marriage, divorce, or a court ordered name change, you will need to obtain a new passport. Once you have a new passport, the Department of State recommends that you apply for a new U.S. visa **to make it easier for you to travel to and from the United States**.

[I changed my name. Is my US visa with my old name still valid](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/frequently-asked-questions/about-basics.html#:%7E:text=If%20your%20name%20has%20legally,I%20changed%20my%20name.)

*My take on it is that it is still valid however you **may** have problems like being stopped and taken to secondary inspection etc, basically an inconvenience.*