# No middle name on US visa but new passport has middle name

Tags: visas

Old Passport- My name on expired Indian Passport [Surname], Given Name- [First Name].
US Visa - [Surname], [First Name]. US visa is valid till 2030.

New Passport- I recently renewed by Indian Passport but didn't realize that it has my middle name.
Surname- [Surname], Given Name- [First Name Middle Name].

My new passport has middle name but its not there on US visa from old passport. Would this be an issue when flying?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you still have the expired passport (with the US visa) in your possession?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I have a valid US visa which is valid till 2030. I am planning to include my middle name i my renewed passport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/168449/i-have-a-valid-us-visa-which-is-valid-till-2030-i-am-planning-to-include-my-mid)